# How can i add components from index.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to import my components from index.js, this file index.js i created in components folder

`index.js` like this:

```
export const Component1 = () => import('./forms/Component.vue')
```

currently i am importing like this

```
import Component1 from '../components/forms/Component'
```

and i want to import like this:

```
import { Component1 } from '@/components'
```

do this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your components directory would need to have an index.js file which exports the components as named exports.

```
export { default as Component1 } from './src/components/Component1/Component1.vue'
```

The problem with this is that the order of the components becomes important when importing each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line to your `webpack.config.js` and restart webpack.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'), // this line
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},
```

Comment: i am not using webpack

Comment: i just using vuejs3

Comment: Well I dont think you can achieve that behaviour without webpack.

Comment: should i create that file or also i need to install webpack?

Comment: I would suggest going with [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org). Create new project and just install your src directory to new project.

Comment: my proyect is not new. it's already in production

Comment: @react1 You'll need to have a bundler for vue, either a custom webpack config, vue-cli (which internally uses webpack as well) or vite (which is using rollup). And there you'll need to configure it accordingly.

Comment: You can still do it. I would go with creating new project and copy/paste legacy files to new project but. You can go with [other methods](https://medium.com/@d.steinberg79/adding-webpack-a-legacy-vue-js-application-ee48f0ca049) too.